# Linux I have 2 WIFI Adapter everytime I boot up they switched each other to wlan0 and wlan1

Tags: linux, wifi

I have problem everytime I boot up my two wifi adapters switched to wlan0 and wlan1 thus my code is ruined.

Edit: My OS is ParrotOS on amd64 
My Wifiadapters are TP-Link with same models

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Please include more information such as what OS you are using and steps you have tried to correct your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on the order of default assignments of network interfaces. The numbers will get assigned in the order they finish initializing, which is more or less random. The same holds for all primary device nodes in `/dev`, BTW, that's why there are symlinks to them.

So either make your own `udev` rules (see existing questions for that) and assign fixed names for them based on the MAC address or other identification (PCI slot, USB port), or figure out how ParrotOS does [predictable network interface names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/).